# Tensorflow-Custom Function: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

When I use the `K.round` function in the custom loss function, it appeared the following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['sequential_20/dense_240/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_240/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_241/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_241/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_242/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_242/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_243/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_243/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_244/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_244/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_245/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_245/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_246/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_246/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_247/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_247/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_248/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_248/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_249/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_249/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_250/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_250/bias:0', 'sequential_20/dense_251/kernel:0', 'sequential_20/dense_251/bias:0'].
```

Here is my working code sample: (if I use the loss function without `K.round`, it is work)

```
def adjusted_loss(y_true, y_pred): 
    y_pred = K.round(y_pred / 1000) * 1000
    loss = y_pred - y_true
    return loss

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation = LeakyReLU()))
model.compile(loss= adjusted_loss, optimizer= opt)
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is simple, `K.round` is not a differentiable function, thus does not provide gradients (result for them is None), you just can't use any non-differentiable function as a loss function.

Comment: The problem is fixed. This is related to the Tensorflow version. `K.round` is supported in `2.2.0`. My issue is in `2.1.0`

Comment: Add answer with solution and accept it then, you have actually not provided any version info tho, I am leaving the answer here as some people might have face this problem due to unsupported version and find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. This is related to the Tensorflow version. `K.round` is supported in `2.2.0`. My issue is in `2.1.0`